# Rotating an icon back and forth using css

Tags: css

I am trying to rotate an icon continuously to and fro. I have been able to rotate it from -45 deg to 90 deg and now I want it to go back in reverse direction. But it again starts from -45 deg to 90 deg. So, the experience of rotatition appears to be broken. Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="searchColDiv">
<i class="fa fa-search searchIcon rotating"  style="font-size: 100px;" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.searchColDiv{
        text-align: center;
    }

@-webkit-keyframes rotating {
        from {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
          transform: rotate(-45deg);
        }
        to {
          -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
          -o-transform: rotate(90deg);
          transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
      }

     .rotating {
        -webkit-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
        -moz-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
        -ms-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
        -o-animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
        animation: rotating 2s linear infinite;
      }
```

Here is `jsFiddle` link to my code:

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/78kt1p5j/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use  the "[alternate](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations#Making_it_move_back_and_forth)" value aside infinite .

> **Making it move back and forth**
>
> ...That’s easily accomplished by setting animation-direction to alternate

```
animation: rotating 2s linear infinite alternate;
```

https://jsfiddle.net/78kt1p5j/1/